# Why does $.ajax respond with 200 when I send invalid login creds?

Tags: jquery

I have an $.ajax function as follows:

```
$.ajax({
         url: urlIn,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "BASIC bogus:bogus");
         },
         complete: function (xhr) {
             if (xhr.status == 401) {
                 alert("Worked");
             }
             else {
                 alert(xhr.status);
             }
         }
     });
```

Yet it returns with 200. What am I missing here?

Comment: The response code is whatever the server returns. Why is the server returning a 200 response to invalid login creds?

Comment: You could check `urlIn` in a browser and see what happens... Are you prompted for credentials? What happens, if you enter bogus values?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins exactly

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the server implementation for that URL isn't checking the basic auth and/or it is just returning a HTTP 200 anyways.

Comment: I've double checked in IIS...it is indeed looking for basic auth